# Can I improve the high-frequencies absorption of a ferrite inductor with two opposite winding directions?

Tags: ferrite, winding

A choke if effective against common mode currents by having two windings in opposite direction around the same core. Currents common to both wires produce opposing magnetic fields and get cancelled.

A ferrite instead works by coupling and dissipating high-frequencies as heat.

Would a toroidal ring be more effective for reducing high-frequencies if a single wire is wound in a direction (right-hand) for half of the circumference and then in the opposite direction (left-hand) for the second half, and then coming out of the ring next to the point of entrance?

[image]

Comment: it would be easier to wind, but I'm not sure that's sufficient advantage to overcome the fact that it would not work.

Comment: You can just as well omit the ferrite.  The coil will only have free-air inductance.

Comment: It's not so much that the unwanted high frequency stuff gets dissipated as heat, but more like it isn't allowed to pass through, more like an electromagnetic gate keeper (much like how light can't pass *through* a mirror but at the same time, it isn't *absorbed* by it either). Common mode chokes need to be placed along *both* legs of the circuit to work properly, it has to cover the current's return path too (common-mode meaning signals common to all wires).

Comment: @Sam, an inductor blocks without absorbing. But a ferrite, to the extent that it is different from an ordinary inductor, does dissipate energy in the core. Otherwise it would just be an inductor.

Comment: Net flux in the core will be zero, therefore, the inductance will be zero. Therefore, this is not a good idea.